# Why can't I add an item to my vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have watched all tutorials and my steps are correct but I still can't get vector to work. Below is my main function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector list<test>;
    list.push_back(new test());
}
```

I wish to add a custom custom class which is `test`. Header is below

```
#ifndef GIVE_ME_BRAIN_TEST_H
#define GIVE_ME_BRAIN_TEST_H

class test {
  public:
     test();
};
```

The class definition is below

```
#include "test.h"

test::test(){}

#endif //GIVE_ME_BRAIN_TEST_H
```

However, compiler keeps on spitting out this message.

[image: link to image]

Googling all suggests my code is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I apologized if there are many typos, this is y first time asking on stack overflow

Comment: I've edited and formatted the question for you.

Comment: please don't use `new`, it allocates dynamic memory that you'll later need to clean up and isn't needed at all here. just use `.push_back(test())`

Comment: @XiangshuaiGao This is not a place where you assign tasks to people. Your question is actually NOT a question but a task, when you get an error, please try to figure it out by yourself first. Why don't you read the compiler error on your own? You've never tried to figure it out by yourself and post a XY problem, this is why you got downvote.

Comment: It seems that you have known some languages such as java, I guess this is why you use `new` there. What you need to do is to buy a C++ book and read it. Asking questions like this is not helpful for you.

Comment: C++ is a powerful but difficult lauguage. Watching some tutorials means alomst nothing. Reading a book, such as C++ primer plus, before you come here.

Comment: @Yves This is my first time using vector and the YouTube turtoriaI I watched tells me I used the right Syntax. I used new because I want to store pointer, obviously.... anyway, I had it figured out. I did take care to deallocate in the destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `std::vector list<test>` nerds to be declared as `std::vector<test> list` instead. That's actually why the compiler complains.

Second, `std::vector<test>` is a `vector` containing actual `test` *objects*. In your case, `new test()` returns a pointer to a `test` object.  Your vector doesn't accept pointers to `test` objects.

Try this instead:

```
std::vector<test> list;
list.push_back(test());
```

Otherwise it will keep complaining.

Notice that `new` is not used anymore. As mentioned in the comments, do not forget that in C++ (unlike in Java, for example) every call to `new` has to be matched by a call to `delete` in order to avoid memory leaks. There is no automatic garbage collection. If you forget this, the compiler will not complain, but your program will use more and more memory and potentially (eventually) slow down your system and/or crash.

Comment: Oh this seems to be another issue. I see it now from your (updated) compiler message. However the issue mentioned here still needs to be addressed.

Comment: unless you `delete aTest` this will leak, but there's no reason to use `new` here at all. just do `list.push_back(test())`

Comment: IMO the answer would be improved by not mentioning the bad suggestion in the first place.  OP's goal clearly is to add an object to the vector,  not specifically to `new` an object

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions guys, I modified my answer to reflect them more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
std::vector list<test>;
```

But the correct syntax is

```
std::vector<test> list;
```

Also you can't add a pointer to the vector of objects. You need to dereference it:

```
auto tmp = new test();
list.push_back(*tmp);
```

Comment: `list.push_back(test());` , or `list.resize(1)` would be far better than creating a redundant object, saving a copy of it, and leaking the original , as your code does

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Please add   `#include <vector>`

**Second:** The line `std::vector list<test>;` need to be replaced with `std::vector<test> list`

**Third:** `list.push_back` take reference as parameter not pointer, so changed as follows:

```
test *tmp = new test();
list.push_back(*tmp);
```

> The final solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class test {
  public:
     test() {

     }

};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    std::vector<test> list;
    test *tmp = new test();
    list.push_back(*tmp);
}
```

Comment: `.push_back(*(new test()))` will leak memory without even a chance to `delete` it